# integrating jQuery Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

Hi i have this pseudo code:

```
if(cookie set){
    $("#notification").hide();
}
else {
    $("#notification").show();
}
```

How can i integrate the jQuery Cookie plugin, so if it finds a cookie then it doesnt show the #notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($.cookie('whatever')) {
  //exists
} else {
  //nuthin!
}
```

Providing you are using: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

**[edit]** you can also:

```
if ($.cookie('whatever') !== null) {
  //exists
} else {
  //still nuthin
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin:

```
if ($.cookie('the_cookie') ) DO_YOUR_WORK;
```

Answer (score 1):

this code worked for me:

```
<script>
    if ($.cookie('whatever')) {
        alert('exists');
    } else {
       alert('not exists');
    }
    //$.cookie('whatever', 'asd'); writing cookie..
</script>
```